# Divide two Pandas DataFrames using a dictionary as a key

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, key, division

I have a DataFrame `df1`:

```
 df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

df1.head()
   A  B  C  D
0  9  8  1  1
1  9  7  1  6
2  0  6  7  5
3  5  1  6  0
4  4  0  5  4
```

A second DataFrame `df2`:

```
  df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10, 3)), columns=list('FGH'))

df2.head()
   F  G  H
0  8  5  9
1  3  0  7
2  2  5  4
3  3  5  4
4  5  6  6
```

And a Dictionary dict:

```
dict = {"A" : "F", "B" : "F", "C" : "H", "D" : "G" }
```

I would like to divide the two Dataframes using the elements of the dictionary as key: Column A by Column F, Column B by column F, Column C by column H and Column D by column G. The result should be:

```
df3.head

0 1.125 1.000 0.111 0.200
1 3.000 2.333 1.429 NA
...
```

Thanks.

Comment: can you show your efforts, this is not that difficult to do

Comment: What do you mean by my efforts? I do not have any idea on how to start. I thought about merging them, but still I do not know how to tell pandas to divide two columns in the same DataFrame using a dict as a key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over the items of your dictionary, and divide the keys which form the column names in `df1` with the values (column names of `df2`). These form a series object with it's name corresponding to the keys. Concatenate these along columwise direction.

Finally, `reindex` them according to the columns of `df1` to preserve the ordering.

```
df = pd.concat([pd.Series(df1[k]/df2[v], name=k) for k,v in my_dict.items()], axis=1)
df.reindex(columns=df1.columns)
```

[image]

***Note:*** I've changed the name of your dictionary, as it is not advisable to use `dict` to name them which also corresponds to a built-in type by the way.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is use `/` operator directly to Columns or DataFrame Series.

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame() #initialize an empty dataframe
for i in dict:
    df3[i+"/"+dict[i]] = df1[i]/df2[dict[i]]


df3.head()
```

[image]